# Problems handled by the last packet in reliable UDP

Tags: java, udp, p2p, file-transfer

```
public class Sender2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            if (args.length < 4) {
                System.err.println("Usage: java Sender2 <ipAddress> <port> <filePath> <extra>");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            final String ipAddress = args[0];
            final int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            final String filePath = args[2];
            final String extra = args[3];
            createAndSend(ipAddress, port, filePath, extra);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void createAndSend(final String ipAddress,final int port,final String filePath,final String extra) throws IOException {

        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setSoTimeout(100);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        File file = new File(filePath);
        String fileName = file.getName();
        long fileSize = file.length();
        int totalPackets = (int) Math.ceil((double) fileSize / 1024);

        byte buf[] = (extra+totalPackets+";"+fileName).getBytes();
        DatagramPacket requestPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
        socket.send(requestPacket);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        // 发送文件数据包
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPackets; i++) {
            final int sequenceNumber = i;
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int len;
                        DatagramPacket packet;
                        while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            // 构造数据包
                            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            outputStream.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(sequenceNumber).array());
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                            byte[] packetData = outputStream.toByteArray();
                            // 发送数据包
                            packet = new DatagramPacket(packetData, packetData.length, address, port);
                            // 等待确认消息
                            boolean ack = false;
                            int tries = 0;
                            socket.setSoTimeout(500); // 增加等待时间
                            while (!ack) {
                                try {
                                    socket.send(packet);
                                    byte[] ackBuffer = new byte[1024];
                                    DatagramPacket ackPacket = new DatagramPacket(ackBuffer, ackBuffer.length);
                                    socket.receive(ackPacket);
                                    int ackSeqNum = ByteBuffer.wrap(ackPacket.getData()).getInt();
                                    if (ackSeqNum == sequenceNumber) { // 收到确认消息
                                        ack = true;
                                    }
                                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                                    tries++;
                                    socket.send(packet);
                                    if (tries >= 20) {
                                        System.err.println("Failed to receive ACK for packet " + sequenceNumber + ", giving up.");
                                        fis.close();
                                        socket.close();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            fis.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(fileSize, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.close();

        if (fileName.endsWith("jpg") || fileName.endsWith("png") || fileName.endsWith("jpeg") || fileName.endsWith("gif") || fileName.endsWith("bmp")) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageWrap(filePath, "5", "1", "1"));
        } else {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageWrap(filePath, "5", "2", "2"));
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Receiver2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        receiveAndCreate(port);
    }

    public static void receiveAndCreate(int port) throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket requestPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(requestPacket);
        InetAddress address = requestPacket.getAddress();
        String getFileMsg = new String(requestPacket.getData(), 0, requestPacket.getLength());
        if(!getFileMsg.contains("F1.2")){
            System.out.println("Invalid request message");
            socket.close();
            return;
        }
        String []getFileMsgSplit = getFileMsg.split(";");
        String format = null;
        String groupid = null;
        String fileName = null;
        int totalPacket = 0;
        if(getFileMsgSplit.length == 4 ){
            format = getFileMsgSplit[0];
            groupid = getFileMsgSplit[1];
            totalPacket = Integer.parseInt(getFileMsgSplit[2]);
            fileName = getFileMsgSplit[3];
        }else if(getFileMsgSplit.length == 3 ){
            format = getFileMsgSplit[0];
            totalPacket = Integer.parseInt(getFileMsgSplit[1]);
            fileName =getFileMsgSplit[2];
        }

        File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/chat/"+fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // 接收文件数据包
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPacket; i++) {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData(), 4, packet.getLength() - 4);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int readLength = 0;
            while ((readLength = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                fos.write(data, 0, readLength);
            }
            // 发送确认消息
            byte[] ackBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array();
            DatagramPacket ackPacket = new DatagramPacket(ackBuffer, ackBuffer.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
            socket.send(ackPacket);
        }

        fos.close();
        socket.close();

        if(format!=null){
            if(format.equals("F1.27")){
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageWrap(address.getHostAddress(),"3",fileName,"0"));
            }else if(format.equals("F1.28")){
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageWrap(address.getHostAddress(),"4",fileName,groupid));
            }
        }
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageWrap("restart","2"));
    }
    
}
```

Why the sender and receiver are not working as expected，I send a file and the part received by the receiver is always missing less than 1kb.I realized that it may be the handling of the last package, but it didn't solve it anyway.Please give the modified code and give an explanation.

Comment: *"not working as expected"* - this is not an error description. You need to explain both what your expectations are and what exactly happens contrary to your expectations. *" but I still didn't understand anything"* - which says only says that there is something you don't understand but not what. Impossible to help based on this. *" reliable UDP libraries that work well, please recommend them as well"* - UDP is an unreliable protocol. Any reliability needs to be explicitly implemented on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this is my first issue, there is still a lot to be desired, and I have fixed the issue description